# Python multiprocessing - Should I create a new pool at each iteration or share it across iterations?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function with a while loop. At each iteration, I need to apply a function in parallel, to each row of a large array, and then I need to use the result of this for the rest of the iteration, to obtain a new array for the next iteration.

The details are not important, but I want to figure out if I should create a new pool at each iteration, or if I should start the pool before I initiate the while loop, and just keep using it. I am new to `multiprocessing`.

Here's a pseudo-code that can't be run, but should give an idea.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count)

def f():
    pass 

def option1():
    """This version creates a new pool at each iteration."""
    while True:
        # Run in parallel
        pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
        results = []
        for i in range(N):
            results.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (params,)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        # Grab the results for this iteration
        iteration_results = [result.get() for result in results]

        # Do something with `results` so that the results can be used in the next `while` loop iter

    return foo # return something at the end

def option2():
    """This version creates a single pool, and uses it at each iteration."""
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    while True:
         results = []
         for i in range(N):
              results.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (params,)))
         iteration_results = [result.get() for result in results]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return foo # return something
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second option should be used.
That is the whole idea of having a "pool" to start with.

Creating a sub-process worker is somewhat costly compared with other operations - it uses a lot of system resources and time.

It is only if the task you are calling leaks memory (by calling low-quality or disposable low-level code not written in Python) that subprocesses should not be reused, and even them, one probably would be better re-using the same processes sometimes around, and just recreate the pool after some N interations.